# Buttons overriding set height/width (appearing too big) when creating them in a for loop

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a method that creates an array of buttons (simulating a grid). The user can click the buttons and a "marker" (image) will appear on it. The problem I have is that even though I'm setting height and width within my method, when it is called, the buttons appear way too big. Important to note that when the user clicks the button, it "shrinks" to the size I specified... Weird. Here is my method:

```
def create_grid(self, leng) :
    try:
        global board
        board = grid.Grid(leng)


        frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        buttons = []
        for row_index in range(0,leng) :
            row = []
            for column_index in range(0,leng) :
                button = tkinter.Button(frame, height=36, \
                    width = 36, text = "  ", \
                    command=lambda row=row_index, \
                        column=column_index: \
                        self.button_clicked(row,column))
                button.grid(row=row_index, column=column_index)
                row.append(button)
            buttons.append(row)

        self.gomuko_buttons = buttons
        return frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    except TypeError:
        return
```

[image: Issue]

Also, the function that executes when the button is pressed is the following:

```
def button_clicked(self,row,column) :
    global turns
    grid.Comp = False
    board.place_marker(row, column)
    button = self.gomuko_buttons[row][column]


    button['image'] = self.photo1
    button['state'] = 'disabled'
    turns = turns + 1
```

Any hint? :(

EDIT:

I solved it thanks to Bryan Oakley's response. Turns out the behaviour for width and height is different for images and text. I solved the problem by simply adding a blank image to the loop, like the following:

```
button = tkinter.Button(frame, height=0, \
                    width = 0, text = " ", image = self.blank, \
                    command=lambda row=row_index, \
                        column=column_index: \
                        self.button_clicked(row,column))
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is more to the problem then you are telling us. For example, your code shows that you are creating a button with a blank label, but the picture shows a button with an image. Are you giving the button an image at some point?

Comment: Definitely missed that... Yes, when the button is clicked, an image will appear. I'll add the piece of code that does that to the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, you *think*  you are giving the button a width of 36 pixels, but you are actually giving it a width of 36 characters. In your callback I'm guessing you're giving the button an image, which causes the button to shrink.

In Tkinter, the width option is interpreted differently depending on whether the button has an image or text. If it has just text, it specifies a width in "average sized characters" (actually, the width of the 0 (zero). If you give the button an image, the width option is interpreted as pixels.

This behavior is documented. See, for example, http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button.config-method

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! in my loop, I added a blank image and set w,h to 0 (so it calculates it itself).